# Regex lookbehind matching word preceding expression in brackets

Tags: regex, lookbehind

Is it possible to use Regex lookbehind expression to match **all** the words preceding whatever is in square brackets, matching words **consectetur** and **libero** in this example?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [adipiscing] elit. Nunc eu tellus vel nunc pretium lacinia. Proin sed lorem. Cras sed ipsum. Nunc a libero [quis] risus sollicitudin imperdiet.

I want to delimit dictionary entries in MS Word from the entry contents. Entries are followed by a phonetic transcription in square brackets, and once they are selected this way I'd increase their font and thus have them differentiated from the rest of the text and delimited from the content.

**EDIT**: The expression that Kent gave works perfectly with one-word entries, e.g:

**boiling ['boilin]  adj  1. vreo, uzavreo, kipući 2. razjaren, uzrujan**

with hyphenated two-word entries such as:

**boiling-point ['boilin point] s vrelište**

but the first word of phrasal verbs and other two-word entries is left out, which means that in the entries such as:

**bolt out ['bault'aut] vt isključiti; izlanuti**

the match is **out** and not **bolt out**, as I would need it.

Since this is a dictionary and I can apply the regex expression for each letter range separately, I'd be able to solve this problem if I had a regular expression that will search for the first word starting with a specific letter which precedes the brackets, match that word and the word that follows. For "B" entries as in my examples, that would mean that the expression would match either single words beginning with letter B, hyphenated two-word entries as **boiling-point** and would match "**bolt**" in the phrasal verbs such as "**bolt out**" along with the preposition that follows it, i.e "out" in this case.

There may be only a few, if any, two-word entries in my dictionary where the words in these entries begin with the same letter, and I really can live with such a small margin of error.

**EDIT2**: I put paragraph breaks before square brackets and now I have my entries at the end of the previous line, like this:

**[aidwulf] s zool vrsta hijene (Proteles cristata) Aron's beard**

**[earanzrod] s bot divizma (Ver- bascum Thapsus) Abacca**

**[a'baid'on] vi biti na pomoći, stajati uz bok abide with**

**Aaron's beard** is an entry for the second line beginning with square brackets, **Abacca** is the entry for the third line beginning with square brackets and so on.

To solve my problem I need two regular expressions.First I need a regular expression to match every letter Aa in the words that begin with Aa and only in words before the last in every line. In my examples that would match **A** in **Aaron's** in the first example and **a** in **abide** in the third example. Then I'd replace this letter with an asterisk to get ***ron's beard** and ***bide with**

The second regular expression would match every last word, (including hyphenated **two-words** compounds) in every line and words that begin with asterisk I previously created.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please extend your example. What exactly do you want to have as result after matching the string against the regular expression? And how does the expression you are working with look so far? Are you trying to match the brackets?

Comment: which understanding is right? 1)you want to match from the beginning of the line till the first `[foo]` 2) you want to match from the first `b/B` until the first `[foo]`?

Comment: 2) is what I'm looking for Kent, I want to match from the first (closest to the brackets) word beginning with letter B up to the first square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need look ahead, not look-behind:

```
\w+(?=\s*\[[^]])
```

test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur [adipiscing] elit. Nunc eu tellus vel nunc pretium lacinia. Proin sed lorem. Cras sed ipsum. Nunc a libero [quis] risus sollicitudin imperdiet."|grep -Po '\w+(?=\s*\[[^\]])'
consectetur
libero
```

**EDIT**

try this regex:

```
[bB].+?(?=\s*\[[^]])
```

still test with grep:

```
kent$  cat file
boiling ['boilin] adj 1. vreo, uzavreo, kipući 2. razjaren, uzrujan
with hyphenated two-word entries such as:
boiling-point ['boilin point] s vrelište
but the first word of phrasal verbs and other two-word entries is left out, which means that in the entries such as:
bolt out ['bault'aut] vt isključiti; izlanuti

kent$  grep -oP '[bB].+?(?=\s*\[[^]])' file
boiling
boiling-point
bolt out
```

Comment: Thank you a million Kent, it works like a charm for single word entries! Is it possible for this expression to include multi-word entries separated by hyphen such as "criss-cross" in the match?

Comment: try to change the `\w` into `[\w-]`

Comment: Now it's hundred percent perfect :) Thank you a lot Kent!

Comment: I didn't realize that a number of entries will be phrasal verbs and similar two-word entries Kent and now I have a problem .The entry preceding the brackets is in bold format, can you give a expression that will catch whatever is in bold before the brackets?

Comment: @TotoKalvera regex can match text, but cannot handle style... regex cannot match bold,italic ... font size=n etc..

Comment: Thank you Kent, let me ask one more question please. Is it possible for this expression to look ahead of the brackets, until it match a word beginning with a specific letter, and match that word and everything that follows until the brackets? That would solve my problem:)

Comment: @TotoKalvera can you edit your question and make an example for the new requirement pls?

Comment: @TotoKalvera check the EDIT in answer.

Comment: It workssss, yahooo!I've checked on a sample from my dictionary, it is perfect, thank you a milion Kent.

Comment: I'd upvote it a hundred times Kent, but I can't, I don't have enough reputation (have 8 and it takes 15) to vote as yet.

Comment: Kent, tried again, and unfortunately there's a problem, sorry to bother again. When I have two square brackets in the same line the expression matches words beginning with B **within** the first square brackets, even if the word doesn't begin with B, picks any B in the word, and starts a new match which ends before the next square brackets. Can you fix it please Kent?

Comment: The problem with starting matches from the words in brackets is solved, but it still picks letter B in the middle of the word and starts a new match, in cases when there are more than one square brackets in the line. When I have only one square brackets in the line no problems whatsoever.

Comment: @TotoKalvera that is what regex match does. If your target is always at the beginning of a line, you could add `^` to the beginning of the regex. otherwise a text like `xxfooxxfooxxfooxx` if the regex is `foo`, it has 3 matches. look-behind doesn't support dynamic length.

Comment: I understand Kent. I think I've found the way to solve my problem, hope it won't bother you to give it another try. I've edited my original post, it's under EDIT2, could you please take a look?